# Retrieve text from sup tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have to extract the a href values from the given code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="left ">
<a href="reference" >Refer</a>see this
<sup class="super"><a href=​"#src1" onclick=​"dosomething;​" title=​"1" >​1​</a>​</sup>
</td>
<td class="td_right2" style="padding-top: .25em"></td>
</tr>
..

</table>
```

My code is

```
 for(Element info: div3.select("tr")){
 Elements aqInfo= companyB.select("td") 
 String href=aqInfo.text(); 
 }
```

href only gives me the text other than the text inside tag

How do I get the text and href tags inside the sup tag?

EDIT: I realised that the page source looks something like this

```
<tr><td class="left "><a href="reference" ">Reference</a>see this <sup class="super_src"></sup></td><td class="right" style="padding-top: .25em"></td></tr>
```

The 'inspect element' in firefox showed the `<a>` inside `<sup>` and I need the contents of this `<a>`. 
Correct me if I am wrong but I think that `Jsoup.connect(url).get();` gives the source document and Inspect element gives the currenly loaded page. Is there a way that I can retrieve the page after the page has completely loaded?

Comment: Will jQuery solution work for you?

Comment: What exactly in the above HTML should the code return? The whole HTML between `<sup>` and `</sup>`?

Comment: explain better what information you want to extract from your document

Comment: I want to extract the text and href which is '#src1' and '1' in the above html. The code would work fine if my Document doc contained the <a> tag. It doesn't. But my webpage does!. How do I make sure the doc gets populated only after the webpage has completely loaded?

Comment: Its a different question that you are asking now `How do I make sure the doc gets populated only after the webpage has completely loaded?` so you better post a new one

Comment: Added new Question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150319/populate-doc-only-after-the-page-is-completely-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
Element mySup= doc.select("sup.super").first();
String linkHref = mySup.child(0).attr("href");
String linkVal = mySup.child(0).text();
```

explanation:

Select element with `sup` tag and `super` class
access its first child which is `a` tag , then access its `href` attribute

to get all `href` and `text inside the a` from all `a` you should do

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

Comment: @Daniel-Thank you for the code. But it didn't work! The problem is - the source page does not contain the 'a' tag inside the 'sup' tag. But when I do Inspect element I find the 'a' tag. How do I extract this content? Is there anything similar to .ready of jquery in jsoup?

Comment: are you sure that your `doc` is valid and really got the html code that you have posted? did the `Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");` returned you list with elements ?

Comment: look here http://jsoup.org/ do `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your web site url").get();` then do `Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");` this will give you all `a` that got `href`  attributes

Comment: The Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get(); does not contain the tag. But when i manually save the  webpage the the <a> is present inside <sup>.

Comment: so your question should have been: `how do i fetch data from this website` , just curios : try `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yourWebSite.com").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get()`

Comment: I realised that only later. JSoup.connect(...).userAgent(...).get(); also gives me the same output!!

Comment: I recommend you to open a new question `how to connect to this address and get its content , i tried this and this and it wont work...`