# Populate doc only after the page is completely loaded

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am retrieving data form a certain website. The `<a>` inside `<sup>` is available only after the page is completely loaded i.e.javascript adds the `<a>` tag to the page.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="left ">
<a href="reference" >Refer</a>see this
<sup class="super"><a href=​"#src1" onclick=​"dosomething;​" title=​"1" >​1​</a>​</sup>
</td>
<td class="td_right2" style="padding-top: .25em"></td>
</tr>
..

</table>
```

So,when I do

```
Document doc=JSoup.connect(...).userAgent(...).get();
```

The doc doesnot contain the `<a>` tag.
How do I make sure that the doc gets populated with 'a' tag as well.Is there any function in Jsoup similar to `.ready` in JQuery?

Comment: Is there any way to do it? Or should I drop using Jsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is a HTML parser, not a webbrowser. Like as most HTML parsers, Jsoup doesn't execute any JavaScript code.

You need instead a HTML parser which can execute JavaScript. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is such one, it's a GUI-less webbrowser designed for unit-testing purposes and is capable of executing JavaScript contained in the webpage which may modify the HTML DOM tree. You could try using it instead.